# Auto fill on2many field on form load odoo 8

Tags: one-to-many, odoo-8, autofill

I have tried to create a functional field with type="one2many" and auto fill on form load. I tried below code:

**Code 1:**

```
'flat_members1': fields.function(_get_flat_members, relation="family.info", method=True, type="one2many", multi='flat_fkk'),

def _get_flat_members(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    cr.execute("Select * from family_info where flat="+str(flat_id)+"")
    cr_res = cr.dictfetchall()
    res = {}
    for data in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
        res[data.id] = self.pool.get('family.info').search(cr,uid,[('flat', '=', flat_id)])
    return values
```

**Code 2:**

```
    member_ids = []
    for res in cr_res:
         member_ids.append((0,0,{'name':res.get('name'),
                               'flat':res.get('flat'),

                               }))
    values.update(family_members1=member_ids)
    return values
```

In both way i got an error:

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Please suggest me a solution thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Odoo8 new api:

```
flat_members1 = fields.One2many(compute='_get_flat_members',
                             comodel_name='family.info',
                             string='flat_members1',
                             store=True)


@api.one
@api.depends('flat_id')
def _get_flat_members(self):
    member_ids = []

    # get member_ids

    self.flat_members1 = member_ids
```